# Powershell Script Troubleshooting

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am working on a script that will check a folder and return the last file date modified time stamp. It will then compare the Current System Time and find the difference between the two and if time is greater than 20 minutes if will send out an email notification.

When debugging/running it I get the following error:

> New-TimeSpan : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.
>   At C:\Users\jalden\Desktop\CalderaMonitoring-Part1.ps1:7 char:14
>   +       $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-TimeSpan], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewTimeSpanCommand

**Here is my Script:**

```
$src="c:\test\"
$sendmail=$false

Get-Item -path $src | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
Foreach-Object 
{ 
    #write-host $_.fullname
    $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)

    if ($dtdiff.minutes -gt 20)
    {
        $strbody=$strbody +$_.fullname+ " - Created Time: "  +$_.LastWriteTime +"`r`n"
        $sendmail=$true
    }       
}

#$strbody

if($sendmail -eq $true)
{
    # Email components
    $strFromAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
    $strToAddress = "abc@xyz.net"
    $strMessageSubject = "Files not uploaded in the last 20 minutes"
    $strMessageBody = $strbody
    $strSendingServer = "smtp.gmail.com"
    $SMTPPort = "587"
    $emailSmtpUser = "abc@xyz.net"
    $emailSmtpPass = "testasfasdfa"

    # Email objects
    $objSMTPMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage         $strFromAddress, $strToAddress, $strMessageSubject, $strMessageBody
    $objSMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SMTPClient( $strSendingServer, $SMTPPort )
    $objSMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true
    $objSMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass );
    $objSMTPClient.Send($objSMTPMessage)
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: While this is not your error issue, don't forget that `.Minutes.` could be 0, where `.TotalMinutes` would show you something that was days old.

Comment: I also don't think you need the `Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}` at all.  In my basic testing on my box - that wasn't necessary in any way to continue in the stream... not sure what you were trying to do there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One the second line below, you don't provide any input to `ForEach-Object`, so `$_` is `$null`

```
Get-Item -path $src | Foreach {$_.LastWriteTime}
  Foreach-Object { 
  #write-host $_.fullname
  $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)

  if ($dtdiff.minutes -gt 20){
    $strbody=$strbody +$_.fullname+ " - Created Time: "  +$_.LastWriteTime +"`r`n"
    $sendmail=$true
    }       
}
```

Change it to:

```
Get-Item -path $src | ForEach-Object { 
  #write-host $_.fullname
  $dtdiff = New-TimeSpan ($_.LastWriteTime) $(Get-Date)

  if ($dtdiff.TotalMinutes -gt 20){
    $strbody=$strbody +$_.fullname+ " - Created Time: "  +$_.LastWriteTime +"`r`n"
    $sendmail=$true
    }       
}
```

As [@gravity notes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41271828/powershell-script-troubleshooting/41272055#comment69745201_41271828), you should use `$dtdiff.TotalMinutes` rather than `$dtdiff.Minutes` if the `if` statement

Comment: One last question. If I wanted to return the results of only the latest file I know I would need to use Get-ChildItem but what syntax would I use to return the latest file?